# Listview color list

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, parameter-passing

I want to get to another activity by clicking on Listview item (for example color list) by pressing on black ' I want to get to another activity with black background). Thats what I have for now:
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList allColors;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    final ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.colorList);
    allColors= new ArrayList<>();
    allColors.add("Blue");
    allColors.add("Yellow");
    allColors.add("Green");
    allColors.add("Red");
    allColors.add("Grey");
    allColors.add("Black");
    allColors.add("Orange");
    allColors.add("Purple");

    ArrayAdapter<String>myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,allColors);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to get to a new Activity by pressing an item on the listview. I have a list of colors, by clicking on one of the items I need to get to a new activity with the same color on the background

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum` with `HashMap` as color names and its hex codes storage, and then pass hex code of color as `String` for second `Activity` via `Intent`:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String> allColors= new ArrayList<>(8);
        allColors.add(Color.Blue.toString());
        allColors.add(Color.Yellow.toString());
        allColors.add(Color.Green.toString());
        allColors.add(Color.Red.toString());
        allColors.add(Color.Grey.toString());
        allColors.add(Color.Black.toString());
        allColors.add(Color.Orange.toString());
        allColors.add(Color.Purple.toString());

        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.colorList);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, allColors);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("BackgroundColor", Color.fromString(((TextView)view).getText().toString()).getHexCode());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public enum Color {
        Blue("#0000FF"),
        Yellow("#FFFF00"),
        Green("#00FF00"),
        Red("#FF0000"),
        Grey("#808080"),
        Black("#000000"),
        Orange("#FFA500"),
        Purple("#800080");

        Color(String color) {
            this.colourCode = color;
        }

        final String colourCode;
        private final static Map<Color, String> colorNames = new HashMap<>(8);


        static {
            colorNames.put(Blue, "Blue");
            colorNames.put(Yellow, "Yellow");
            colorNames.put(Green, "Green");
            colorNames.put(Red, "Red");
            colorNames.put(Grey, "Grey");
            colorNames.put(Black, "Black");
            colorNames.put(Orange, "Orange");
            colorNames.put(Purple, "Purple");
        }

        public String getHexCode() {
            return colourCode;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return colorNames.get(this);
        }

        public static Color fromString(String name) {
            for (Color key : colorNames.keySet()) {
                if (colorNames.get(key).equals(name)) {
                    return key;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        String backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            backgroundColor = intent.getStringExtra("BackgroundColor");
        }
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add `SecondActivity` to `AndroidManifest.xml`